# Accessing object properties with ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to disable or enable a button based using an `ng-if`.

The first `ng-if` works as I expect it, and it disables the button if the page is not greater than one.

The second `ng-if` works, in that it does not disable the button, but clicking the button does not increment the variable `page`, or if it does, the change is not reflected in the text.

I'm getting no errors when I click it.

Is it something to do with the `s.pages.length` comparison?

```
<div ng-repeat="s in scripts track by $index">
    <div ng-click=''>
        <b>Name</b>: <input type="text" ng-model="scriptNames[$index]"  size="10" /> <input type="button" value='Rename' ng-click='renameScript($index)'/>
        </br>
        <b>Preview</b>: <textarea ck-editor class="ckeditor" ng-model="s.pages[page].versions[0]" value="{{s.pages[page].versions[0]}}" ></textarea>
        </br>
        <span ng-if="page > 1">
        <input type="button" value='previous page' ng-click='page = page - 1'/>
        </span>
        {{page+1}}
        <span ng-if="page < s.pages.length">
            <input type="button" value='next page' ng-click='page = page + 1'/>
        </span>
        </br>
        <input type="button" value='Save Edits' ng-click='updateScript($index)'/>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="button" value='Delete Script' ng-click='deleteScript($index)'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's another example where something unexpected is happening. I am able to increment  page, but I am unable to decrement the page.

This is code below is immediately above the code above. They're both accessing the same variable. I'm not sure if that would cause a problem.

```
<textarea ck-editor class="ckeditor" ng-model="script[page]" value="{{script[page]}}"  rows='10' cols='80'></textarea>
<span ng-if="page+1 > 1">
        <input type="button" value='previous page' ng-click='page = page - 1'/>
</span>
{{page+1}}
<input type="button" value='next page' ng-click='page = page + 1'/>
</br>
<input type="button" value='Submit script' ng-click='submitScript()'/>
```

Comment: Is this something you could show in a Fiddle?

Comment: Is 'page' a property on your controller?

Comment: That was a trick question ;). Each ng-repeat element gets it's own scope so when you do page = page + 1 you're incrementing a page property on the child scope. Try $parent.page instead or call functions in the ng-click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngIf` creates another scope. So you have to access the `page` property on `$parent`...

```
<input type="button" value='previous page' ng-click='$parent.page = $parent.page - 1'/>
```

Jsbin... http://jsbin.com/beguhoxo/1/edit?html,js,output